# android tabbed layout creates separated files in mobile

Tags: android

I have this android app, i've created a tabbed layout and have 2 tabs.
The issue is, when i install the .apk file to my phone it creates three icons, one with the first tab's content, the other with the second tab's content and the last one with both tabs in the same app..

How can this be?
Here is my main java class:

```
import android.app.TabActivity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.content.res.Resources;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.TabHost;



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables   

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost   

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Reusable TabSpec for each tab  

        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab   

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)   

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Ditari.class);   //Initialize a  

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("ditari").setIndicator("Ditari" 
                     ).setContent(intent);   

        tabHost.addTab(spec);    // Do the same for the other tabs   

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Postime.class);   

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("postime").setIndicator("Postime").setContent(intent);   

        tabHost.addTab(spec);   


        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

    }

}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ditari"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Ditari"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Postime"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i updated the question with my manifest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove intent filter from Ditari and Postime

Something like this

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Ditari"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Postime"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

The reason for three different icons was that you were specifying each and every activity of the application as the LAUNCHER activity.